# Как я могу управлять применением z-index? Hover отменяет z-index до завершения transitions

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь создать веб-страницу в HTML & CSS с 6 столбцами. Желаемое поведение состоит в том, что, когда пользователь наводит курсор на 1 столбец, он расширяется над остальными 5 для отображения дополнительной информации, а когда пользователь уводит курсор, столбец сжимается обратно.

Каждый div имеет правила в CSS для ширины `transition` и  `margin-left`, чтобы развернуться на всю ширину экрана. При наведении `z-index`, также принимает значения `1000`, чтобы выбранный столбец покрывал остальную часть содержимого.

Однако, когда наведение курсора  прекращается, то  `z-index` сразу возвращается к неопределенному значению, и сокращающийся столбец привязывается ко всем  столбцами справа от него, что  нежелательно.

Я надеюсь выяснить, как сохранить у последнего столбца,  самое высокое значение `z-index`, достаточно долго, чтобы он закрылся, а затем был сброшен, чтобы любой другой расширяющийся столбец мог иметь приоритет.

Я попытался использовать `z-index` вместе `transition`, а также с `transition-delay`, однако `z-index`, похоже, не связан каким-либо таймером transition. Даже при группировании его с другими эффектами `transition-delay` столбец сразу же перемещается за всем справа от него, а затем, когда таймер задержки активирован, начинается transition.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.category {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  text-align: center;
}

#column1{
  background-color: #147afaff;
  transition: width 1.5s;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
}#column2{
  background-color: #fa9414ff;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s;
  position:absolute;
  left:16.66%;
  height: 100%;
}#column3{
  background-color: #2bae66ff;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s;
  position: absolute;
  left:33.32%;
  height: 100%;
}#column4{
  background-color: #fdd20eff;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s;
  position:absolute;
  left:49.98%;
  height: 100%;
}#column5{
  background-color: #603f83ff;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s;
  position:absolute;
  left:66.64%;
  height: 100%;
}#column6{
  background-color: #f93822ff;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s;
  position:absolute;
  left:83.30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column1:hover{
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}#column2:hover{
  margin-left: -16.66%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}#column3:hover{
  margin-left: -33.32%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}#column4:hover{
  margin-left: -49.98%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}#column5:hover{
  margin-left: -66.64%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}#column6:hover{
  margin-left: -83.30%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Expanding Columns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="Website Header"></div>
    </header>

    <section id="categories">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="column1" class="category">
        <h1>Column 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column2" class="category">
        <h1>Column 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column3" class="category">
        <h1>Column 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column4" class="category">
        <h1>Column 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column5" class="category">
        <h1>Column 5</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column6" class="category">
        <h1>Column 6</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56884754/7394871

Comment: На мой взгляд, интересный вопрос и эффективное решение проблемы совместной анимации расширения столбцов и анимации с  задержкой z-index. Берите прием на вооружения для своего веб строительства :-)

Comment: теперь я понял откуда вопрос, не заметил этот =)

Comment: [Добавлен ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/999677/28748), собранный из двух ответов: 1.  - адаптивное добавление изображений от `Stranger in the Q` и 2.  ответа с текстовым наполнением

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте, чтобы `z-index` имел мгновенное изменение при `hover` и задержку при `unhover`. Убедитесь, что вы также установили значение по умолчанию.

```
.category {
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 1.5s;
  z-index:0;
}
.category:hover {
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 0s;
}
```

**Полный код:**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.category {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 1.5s;
  z-index:0;
}
.category:hover {
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 0s;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: #147afaff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #fa9414ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.66%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column3 {
  background-color: #2bae66ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33.32%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column4 {
  background-color: #fdd20eff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49.98%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column5 {
  background-color: #603f83ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.64%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column6 {
  background-color: #f93822ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 83.30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column1:hover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column2:hover {
  margin-left: -16.66%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column3:hover {
  margin-left: -33.32%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column4:hover {
  margin-left: -49.98%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column5:hover {
  margin-left: -66.64%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column6:hover {
  margin-left: -83.30%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Expanding Columns</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="Website Header"></div>
  </header>

  <section id="categories">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="column1" class="category">
        <h1>Column 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column2" class="category">
        <h1>Column 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column3" class="category">
        <h1>Column 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column4" class="category">
        <h1>Column 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column5" class="category">
        <h1>Column 5</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="column6" class="category">
        <h1>Column 6</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
 Run code snippetExpand
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56884754/7394871): @Temani Afif

Answer (score 3):

Пробую использовать решение @TemaniAfif, добавляю текст в колонки:

Смотрится интересно.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.category {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 0.5s;
  z-index:0;
}
.category:hover {
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 0s;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: #147afaff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #fa9414ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.66%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column3 {
  background-color: #2bae66ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33.32%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column4 {
  background-color: #fdd20eff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49.98%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column5 {
  background-color: #603f83ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.64%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column6 {
  background-color: #f93822ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 83.30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column1:hover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column2:hover {
  margin-left: -16.66%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column3:hover {
  margin-left: -33.32%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column4:hover {
  margin-left: -49.98%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column5:hover {
  margin-left: -66.64%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column6:hover {
  margin-left: -83.30%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.p1 {
margin:0.5em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
 <section id="categories">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="column1" class="category">
        <h1>Column 1</h1>
  <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p> 
   
      </div>
      <div id="column2" class="category">
        <h1>Column 2</h1>
   <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p> 
      <p class="p1"> Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="column3" class="category">
        <h1>Column 3</h1> 
  <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>  
     <p class="p1"> Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.</p>
  <p class="p1"> Fusce ultricies maximus ante vitae imperdiet. Proin magna orci, pretium nec pretium id, ultricies in risus. Praesent mauris ipsum, semper nec convallis sit amet, vestibulum non enim. </p>   
      </div>
      <div id="column4" class="category">
        <h1>Column 4</h1>
  <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="column5" class="category">
        <h1>Column 5</h1>
  <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="column6" class="category">
        <h1>Column 6</h1>
  <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Связанный ответ: [Как сохранить размер и расположение по центру дочернего изображения при динамически изменяющейся ширине колонки родителя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/999742/28748)

**Добавление svg иконок и блоков текста**

Соединяем два решения:

1. ответ @StrangerintheQ с добавлением изображений, указанный выше, в ссылке и
2. ответ с текстовым наполнением:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.category {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 1.5s;
  z-index:0;
}
.category:hover {
  transition: width 1.5s, margin-left 1.5s,z-index 0s 0s;
}

#column1 {
  background-color: #147afaff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #fa9414ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.66%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column3 {
  background-color: #2bae66ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33.32%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column4 {
  background-color: #fdd20eff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49.98%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column5 {
  background-color: #603f83ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 66.64%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column6 {
  background-color: #f93822ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 83.30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column1:hover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column2:hover {
  margin-left: -16.66%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column3:hover {
  margin-left: -33.32%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column4:hover {
  margin-left: -49.98%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column5:hover {
  margin-left: -66.64%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#column6:hover {
  margin-left: -83.30%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000; 
}
.img1 {
width: calc(100vw / 6);
}
.p1 {
margin:0.5em;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="categories">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="column1" class="category">
        <h1>Column 1</h1> 
   <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f334.svg" /> </div>
   <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="column2" class="category">
        <h1>Column 2</h1> 
   <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f335.svg" /> </div> 
      <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p> 
      <p class="p1"> Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="column3" class="category">
        <h1>Column 3</h1>
    <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f338.svg" /> </div> 
      <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie.Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="column4" class="category">
        <h1>Column 4</h1> 
    <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f339.svg" /> </div> 
      <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="column5" class="category">
        <h1>Column 5</h1>
    <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f340.svg" /> </div> 
      <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie. </p> 
      <p class="p1"> Nullam ornare turpis quis orci hendrerit, vitae varius est tincidunt. In quis malesuada tellus. Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. Integer congue facilisis enim porta pretium. Morbi scelerisque tincidunt purus, vitae rhoncus tortor tristique nec. Nullam laoreet turpis nec felis vehicula finibus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="column6" class="category">
        <h1>Column 6</h1> 
    <div> <img class="img1"  src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f347.svg" /> </div> 
      <p class="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt dignissim nibh a facilisis. Phasellus pretium nisl vel turpis suscipit, quis posuere quam laoreet. Vestibulum fringilla porttitor felis, non lacinia dolor mattis vitae. Donec gravida et purus eu pellentesque. Nam consequat nisl id velit interdum eleifend. Mauris nulla turpis, sollicitudin in vestibulum nec, ornare quis lacus. Proin eros diam, lacinia id blandit a, efficitur eget mauris. Morbi ullamcorper velit non urna malesuada molestie.Aliquam nunc mauris, aliquam quis lectus ut, ultrices lobortis ante. Maecenas tincidunt ligula felis, in consequat lectus finibus eget. Maecenas molestie placerat odio, at malesuada risus consequat id. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```